# How to combine multiple selects?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I combine these two rules into one?

```
#body_splash{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
#body_main{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

I tried

```
#body_splash #body_main
```

and

```
#body_splash#body_main
```

but neither worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use commas to separate them :

```
#body_splash,
#body_main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: damn, that would have been the 3rd thing I tried.  3rd time really is  a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Seperate multiple selectors with a comma

```
#body_splash, #body_main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
div[id^='body_']
```

*Assuming* they both have the same tag, like div, this looks for all divs with an id that starts with "body_"